# os.path.join in python returns 'wrong' path?

Tags: python, os.path

I have the following python os.path output from ipython

```
import os.path as path
path.join("/", "tmp")
Out[4]: '/tmp'
path.join("/", "/tmp")
Out[5]: '/tmp'
path.join("abc/", "/tmp")
Out[6]: '/tmp'
path.join("abc", "/tmp")
Out[7]: '/tmp'
path.join("/abc", "/tmp")
Out[8]: '/tmp'
path.join("def", "tmp")
Out[10]: 'def/tmp'
```

I find outputs 5, 6, 7 and 8 to be counterintuitive. Can somebody please explain if there was a specific reason for this implementation?

Comment: Note that there isn't *any* reason to have an absolute path as non-first argument to `join`. `join` is meant to build *a* path given its components. No path has absolute paths as "sub-path". What would you expect to happen with `join("/", "/tmp")`?

Comment: makes sense! i guess that justifies the implementation well! thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [`os.path.join()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> Join one or more path components intelligently. If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues.

A `/` at the start makes `/tmp` an absolute path.

If you wanted to join multiple path elements that *perhaps* contain a leading path separator, then strip those first:

```
os.path.join(*(elem.lstrip(os.sep) for elem in elements))
```

Special-casing absolute paths makes it possible for you to specify either a relative path (from a default parent directory) *or* an absolute path and not have to detect if you have an absolute or relative path when constructing your final value.

Answer (score 4):

The second strings should not start with a `/`; that creates an **absolute path**. Doing the following worked:

```
>>> path.join('abc/', 'tmp')
'abc/tmp'
```

From the Python documentation:

> If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues.